# R with png() support

Tags: r, heroku

I am building R from source on Heroku via Vulcan, and trying to debug lack of png() support.  I think the issue has to do with discovery of libXmu or equivalent, based on the below output.  How do I pass the compiler a folder to look in for libXmu?  (I can curl one down just fine).

```
checking X11/Intrinsic.h usability... yes
checking X11/Intrinsic.h presence... yes
checking for X11/Intrinsic.h... yes
checking for XtToolkitInitialize in -lXt... yes
using X11 ... yes
checking for KeySym... yes
checking X11/Xmu/Atoms.h usability... no
checking X11/Xmu/Atoms.h presence... no
checking for X11/Xmu/Atoms.h... no
```

Capabilities shows a lack of png and x11:

```
> capabilities()
    jpeg      png     tiff    tcltk      X11     aqua http/ftp  sockets 
   FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE     TRUE     TRUE 
  libxml     fifo   cledit    iconv      NLS  profmem    cairo 
    TRUE     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE    FALSE    FALSE
```

my kitchen sink make call:

```
./configure --prefix=$prefix --enable-R-shlib --with-x --with-libpng --with-jpeglib && make && make install
```

Comment: Other tips for people following in my steps: build with vagrant rather than vulcan.  Work on this topic has been rolled into the heroku-buildpack-r project on github.

Comment: LFTL: [heroku-buildpack-r](https://github.com/virtualstaticvoid/heroku-buildpack-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure you have `X11` and `cairo` support installed, I have come across the same problem and fix by installing `X11, Xt, Xmu` libs and installing `cairo`

and you can refer to

> http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/How-to-get-R-to-compile-with-PNG-support-td3457938.html

Comment: Debugging on a vagrant box and installing the above from source was the great leap forward.